# Android Asset Packs Size

Tags: android, android-assets

Google recently released asset packs for Android.  The docs are available here.  https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery#size-limits

The size limits are phrased a little vaguely.  Does this mean that the sum of the size of all asset packs is capped at 2gb?  Or does this means that each pack is capped at 2gb?

```
The download size limit for each fast-follow and on-demand asset pack is 512 MB.

The download size limit for all install-time asset packs is 1 GB.

The download size limit for all asset packs in an Android App Bundle is 2 GB.

You can use up to 50 asset packs in an Android App Bundle.
```

Comment: It now reads 'The *total* download size limit for all asset packs in an Android App Bundle is 2 GB.' I'd guess it's not '2gb per each of the 50 packs' anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this:

- Max size for all asset packs *combined* = *2 GB*.
- Max *number* of asset packs = *50*.
- Max size of *install-time* asset packs is *1 GB*. (might be more then one, not very clear)
- Max size of each *fast-follow* and *on-demand* asset pack = *512 MB*.