# Google Play Asset Delivery: 2GB size limit for all packets or just for download?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-assets, android-bundle

Google states a 2GB ***Download size limit*** for the Android App Bundle when using Play Asset Delivery.

Does that include all "on-demand" asset packs?
E.g. I have an app with on-demand packs for different languages.
Can I only upload a total of 2GB to the play store for one app?
Or could I upload on-demand packets with a total size of more than 2GB (e.g. 1GB for each language), but only download a maximum of 2GB on the device?

A similar question does not have clear answers: [Android Asset Packs Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700527/android-asset-packs-size)

Has anybody actually tried to explore the limits with on-demand packets?

Comment: Check this https://youtu.be/WW9GevpEo1s?t=1020